# Solving for $a$ in $\arcsin\sqrt a = \arcsin\sqrt b - \dfrac h2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How can I solve

$$\arcsin\sqrt a = \arcsin\sqrt b - \dfrac h2$$

I would like solve for $a$ in terms of $b$ and $h$.

Comment: You really should indicate that you have at least tried something first.

Comment: Why needlessly complicate the problem by using $\sqrt{a}$ and $\sqrt{b}$ rather than simply with $c$ and $d$ where $c = \sqrt{a}$ and $d = \sqrt{b}$?  And why $h/2$ instead of $g = h/2$?  You're making the problem needless confusing because you don't seem to see the structure of the problem.

Comment: Consider $\arcsin\sqrt a=c$, there is no need for the complex RHS. Then as shown in the answers, $\sqrt a=\sin c$ and $a=\sin^2c$, which you can expand $a=\sin^2\left(\arcsin\sqrt b-\dfrac h2\right)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple:  Just take the sine of both sides and square:

$$\sqrt{a} = \sin \left( \sin^{-1} (\sqrt{b}) - h/2\right)$$

or

$$a = \sin^2 \left( \sin^{-1} (\sqrt{b}) - h/2\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

I think I was able to solve the problem. I remembered

$y = \arcsin x$ is equivalent to $\sin y = x$

which turns the original equation to

$a = (\sin(\arcsin\sqrt b - h/2))^2$